# How can I have builds fail if new code is below coverage threshold?

Tags: java, sonarqube, automated-tests, code-coverage, jacoco

Is there any Java testing framework (preferably Jacoco and/or Sonar) that will allow teams with poor code coverage, to forgive the existing code base, but require new code to be above a threshold, (until they can get all of the old code covered!)

Comment: You might also want to ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can add a build plugin to your pom. This one is doing a line coverage check for a minimum of 80%. See [Jacoco doc](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html) for more info.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-check</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I think this only checks total code coverage. I was interested in _new_ code coverage

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that you can do this using [Sonar Quality Gates](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates) and integrating that with your CI server. In Jenkins, you might want to try the [Quality Gates Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/quality-gates).

Comment: i just want to put here, that we use Sonar Quality Gates for this purpose, not directly on jenkins, but with bitbucket integration and pull request merge checks, to prevent such things - it is actually working quite great! as you can define a "error" and a "warning" threshold